# trouble displaying the selected tab with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble displaying only the selected tabbed div with a link:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('ul#tabs>li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $(this).attr('href');
        $(tab).css('display', 'block');
        $(tab).siblings('div').css('display', 'none');
    })
});

</script>
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div id="tabsBox">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="#a">A content</div>
    <div id="#b">B content</div>
    <div id="#c">C content</div>
</div>
```

It's here in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9xrjD/

does any one have any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

You put `#a` instead of `a` in your id, as `#` is already used to define an id you don't need it in the html `id=`

fixed jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9xrjD/2/

Comment: thanks for your help I can't believe the idiocy of my question now, I haven't developed anything in a few weeks and I'm already losing attention doh!

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xrjD/3/)

Replace

```
<div id="#a">A content</div>
<div id="#b">B content</div>
<div id="#c">C content</div>
```

With

```
<div id="a">A content</div>
<div id="b">B content</div>
<div id="c">C content</div>
```

Your function does work, however you weren't actually hiding your `<div>`'s in the CSS.

```
#a, #b, #c {
  display: none;
}
```

Will hide all elements with the ID's `a`, `b` and `c` - not `#a`, `#b` and `#c`.

Comment: his `<li><a /></li>`s are fine as they are just to redirect. don't tell him to replace those unless needed.  What those links will do is go to anchors

Comment: @sircapsalot Sorry, pasted the wrong bit in the rush of things :p my jsFiddle was correct though

Comment: thanks for your help I can't believe the idiocy of my question now, I haven't developed anything in a few weeks and I'm already losing attention doh!